Can you specify a container query in the Azure Ingestion Job API?
I have setup to use the Azure OpenAI Service Ingestion Job API, and now I wonder if it's possible to specify a container query in the API? I have a lot of folders inside my container, and I only want to run the ingestion job on one virtual folder in the container.
I haven't been able to find any information on this topic online or in the API documentation.
Here is my code:
const endpoint = openaiEndpoint; 
const jobId = indexName; 
const apiVersion = "2024-04-01-preview";

const url = `${endpoint}/openai/ingestion/jobs/${jobId}?api-version=${apiVersion}`;

const requestBody = {
    "kind": "SystemCompute",
    "searchServiceConnection": {
        "kind": "EndpointWithKey",
        "key": searchAdminApiKey, 
        "endpoint": searchEndpoint
    },
    "datasource": {
        "kind": "Storage",
        "storageAccountConnection": {
            "kind": "ConnectionString",
            "connectionString": blobStorageConnectionString
        },
        "containerName": "iverdokument",
        "chunking": {
            "maxChunkSizeInTokens": 1024
        },
        "embeddings": [
            {
                "connection": {
                    "kind": "RelativeConnection"
                },
                "deploymentName": "Ada"
            }
        ]
    },
    "completionAction": "cleanUpTempAssets"
};

try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'api-key': openaiApiKey!
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Request successful:', data);
        return data;
    } else {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        console.error('Request failed ingestion:', errorData);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
}

Link to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/rest/api/azureopenai/ingestion-jobs/create?view=rest-azureopenai-2024-07-01-preview&tabs=HTTP

The ingestion API does not offer the possibility to target a specific path within a storage container
